Ergodic Theorem for continuous state space Markov chains
I am a beginner of the continuous state space markov chain and ergodic theorem for markov chain. I was wondering if the following theorem holds:

Consider a irreducible and aperiodic markov chain $\{X_n\}$ in continuous state space S. Denote $P$ as the transition kernel, and denote $\pi$ as its unique stationary distribution. Then we have for any $f \in L^1(S, \pi)$, i.e. $\int_S |f(x)| d\pi(x) < \infty$,
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f(X_n) \stackrel{N\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_S f(x)d\pi(x) = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \pi}[f(x)] \quad\mathrm{ a.e.}$$

Is the theorem true?
My another question is, I think that this theorem (if it is true) indicates that no matter what initial distribution of $X_0$ (initial data point of markov chain) we choose, the average $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f(X_n)$ converges almost surely to the expectation of $f(x)$ under stationary distribution $\pi$. Am I right?
P.S.: I think this may be different from Birkhoff's ergodic Theorem, which requires the measure preserving system. When the initial distribution of $X_0$ is different from the stationary distribution $\pi$, then the chain is not a measure preserving system, right? So we cannot simply apply Birkhoff's ergodic Theorem. This is why I post this questions. If there is anything wrong about my thoughts and considerations, please point it out. Thank you so much!
